# Blender: How To Specify Voxel Coordinates?

Tags: python, blender, voxel

I have been playing around with Blender Voxel Data for a while now, and I'm still not sure how it works.  What i need is to be able to specify the coordinates for each voxel.  I have a data set like this:

```
xx yy zz dd
xx yy zz dd
```

and I have a piece of python code that extracts each dd value, turns them into ASCII characters, and stuffs them into a .bvox file that is headed with the dimensions.  However, none of the xyz coordinates are saved.  How does Blender know where to put each voxel?  I have looked at some texture mapping ideas, but none of them allow me to specify exactly which coordinate to put each voxel.

Any suggestions are gladly accepted!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Does Blender Voxel Data Work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737649/how-does-blender-voxel-data-work)

Comment: Repeating the same question isn't helpful (also repeated in blender.stackexchange which would be the best place for this). There are probably only 2 or 3 devs that have worked on blender's voxel data code and can answer this, so you may need to look through blender's source code yourself to find how it works.